# jsf 2.1 update url without redirect

Tags: jsf-2, url-rewriting, scope, forward

I want to update url but I don't want to use redirect mechanism because I don't want to manage request scope. I already added `phaseListener` for keeping messages in context while redirecting pages, but I started to search solution how can I keep request scoped beans, I found some solutions like flash scope, but just the thing I want: update browser url while changing pages with using forward mechanism. I dont want to do somethings like workaround. I have also tried f:event but browser isnt changed after f:event call.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution in a different way, I am still using redirect, I put id to the flash scope, and then I have addet to the redirected page something like;

```
<f:metadata>
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{omLoginController.init()}"></f:event>
</f:metadata>
```

So by this way page init is invoked and I have initialized page related data in init method.